# Character encoding in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, character-encoding, rtf

I am facing a problem of missing characters during saving them as a **.pdf** or **.rtf** file.I have a richtextbox to take input from user and file saving options of different formats.
When i write something in english in richtextbox and save them then it is all ok.But when i'm writing something rather than english such as..

```
richtextbox1.Text="আমার সোনার বাংলা"; //bangla language i used here
```

And then if i want to save them as .rtf or .pdf format then those file contains spaces or show ????? symbols.But .docx and .txt files are showing those characters right.So how can i overcome this problem for .rtf,.pdf or .html?
I am using **Microsoft Sans Serif** as the font of that richtextbox.I try with **unicode and utf8** encoding to solve that but still no luck..
**EDIT :**
For saving as **.rtf** format i use..

```
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText);
```

Where **sfd** is the **savefiledialog**.
And for **.pdf** i use..

```
iTextSharp.text.Document myDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
            try
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));

                myDocument.Open();

                myDocument.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(richTextBox1.Text));
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
            }
            myDocument.Close();
```

Comment: Some sets are only available in UTF16. In .NET-speak, that is `System.Text.UnicodeEncoding`.

Comment: How do you "save"? Is it the `richtextbox1.SaveFile` method you use? Can that method create PDF?

Comment: Yes it create pdf,i use itextsharp library for that,and even i told earlier it is fine for english language but problem for different language.Do i need to configure richtextbox for that?

Comment: To help you, we need to know how exactly you are *saving them as a .pdf or .rtf* and what goes wrong; that being said, iText(Sharp) does not support explicit ligaturizing of most Asian languages, if that is the issue underneath.

Comment: What font are you using? I have had similar issues where there is no corresponding character in the font I was using, you could try using "Arial Unicode MS" and see what results you get.

Comment: @PaulieWaulie i tried that also,but not succeed..

Comment: Both the PDF and RTF file formats were invented before Unicode came around.  They use a pretty bizarro mix of character sets and code pages.  Ending up with encoding problems certainly isn't that unexpected.

Comment: *myDocument.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(richTextBox1.Text));* --- you don't tell iTextSharp which font to use for your paragraph. Thus, it chooses some default font which I assume to be one of the *Standard 14 Fonts* each PDF viewer has to support out of the box. Unfortunately these standard fonts essentially only contain Western characters. Create a `Font` instance for a font which contains the characters you need and create the paragraph using that font.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, richtextbox1.RTF, Encoding.UTF8);
```